# How to set background image to a particular div using external stylesheet?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to add a background image to a divwhich will b e reffered from external stylesheet but failed to do so.Pls tell me how to do it.

```css
.header {
  height: 278px;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.center {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

.navbar-custom {
  margin: 45px;
}

.color {
  background-color: #7b97ac;
}

.nav {
  font-size: 25px;
}

.nav li a {
  color: #000;
}

.nav li a:hover {
  color: #E50894;
}

.nav .active a {
  color: #E50894;
}

.back {
  background-image: url(../img/home.jpg);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


  <title>Themida Home</title>

  <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">

  <script src="js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="header">
      <img src="img/Themida_logo.png" class="center">



      <nav class="navbar navbar-custom center">

        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mynavbar">
     <span class="icon-bar color"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar color"></span>
     <span class="icon-bar color"></span>
    </button>
        </div>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mynavbar">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
            <li><a href="About Us.html">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.html">SERVICES</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">CONTACT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">LINKS</a></li>
          </ul>

        </div>

      </nav>
    </div>

    <div class="back">

    </div>

  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

[![This is the image i want to use as background
][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg4go.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg4go.jpg)

Please help me.

Comment: I have given my full code so that anyone can understand better

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add the `height`/`width` so that you can see the `background-image`, since it does not have any child

```css
.back {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg4go.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">

</div>
```

If you add some content, you can see the image without adding width or height

```css
.back {
  background-image: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg4go.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="back">
  <br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
</div>
```

Comment: It worked but some portion of background image is missing. The grey border is missing at downwards. May be because of background size cover. Any fix for that?

Answer (score 1):

1. You need to edit the `.back` class in your CSS file and add these:

```css
.back {
background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/Dg4go.jpg');
background-size: cover;
width:600px; /* this can be adjusted to your taste*/
height:200px; /* this can be adjusted to your taste*/
}
```

2. In your HTML file you need to add content to see the image properly e.g

```html
<div class="back">
<br><br><hr><br> <!-- add as many as you can for test purposes -->
</div>
```

Depending on the type of content you intend to add to the div, the `width` and `height` properties in the CSS might need to be tweaked, or even removed. Good luck.

Comment: It worked but some portion of background image is missing. The grey border is missing at downwards. May be because of background size cover. Any fix for that?

Comment: @Akash279 try and add this `background-position: center center;` to the `.back` class in your css file.

Comment: @Akash279 or try tweaking background size using `background-size: 100%;` and `background-origin: content;`

Answer (score 0):

The div has no dimensions (height, width) and therefore the background image won't show. It will only automatically show image if it is an IMG tag